# Nilpotency class of a Nilpotent-Dedekind group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that G is a Nilpotent-Dedekind group. Why is its nilpotency class at most 2? If G is abelian It is obvious. What about if It is not abelian (i.e. Hamiltonian)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dedekind groups are completely classified. Every non-abelian Dedekind group is of the form $G=Q_8 \oplus B \oplus D$, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group, $B$ is an elementary abelian 2-group, and $D$ is a periodic abelian group all of whose elements have odd order. Since $[Q_8,Q_8]=Z(Q_8)=\{\pm 1\}$, the quaternion group is $2$-step nilpotent. Hence $G$ is $2$-step nilpotent.